# How to inject object or create new one in class wrapper for sensor eg DHT22?

Tags: arduino

I want to create class which do init setup and manage sensor throw my class. I created one for WiFi and it works well

```
class WifiClient {
  
  private:
    String ssid;
    String password;

  public:
    WifiClient(String ssid, String password) {
      this->ssid = ssid;
      this->password = password;
    }

    void connect() {
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(this->ssid, this->password);

    }

    boolean is_connected() {
      if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
};
```

But I can't create the same for DHT22.

```
class DHT22CLient {
  
  private:
    DHT sensor;

  public:
    DHT22CLient(uint8_t pin) {
      this->sensor(pin, DHT22);
    }

    void start() {
      this->sensor.begin();
    }

    float getTemperature() {
      return this->sensor.readTemperature()
    }
};
```

I'v got exception

```
dht22_client.h:11:30: error: no match for call to '(DHT) (uint8_t&, int)'
       this->sensor(pin, DHT22);
                              ^
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'DHT::DHT()'
```

Am I dependency injection wrong?

Comment: That's not how dependency injection works in C++, and your code has nothing to do with dependency injection either. DHT22 is defined in another class/library, you are using it without inherit it or include it.

Comment: @hcheung I already tested DHT22 it's pretty easy. However I want to create some abstract layer between my code and third party libs.

Comment: Over-abstraction is another issue. DHT22 library already provide the abstraction necessary for the underneath code, your extra layer of abstraction does not add any value to that, what the difference between your `myClient.getTemperature()` from `DHT22.readTemperature()`.

Comment: @hcheung I can save state of DHT22. One simple example I can create separated methods for getting temperature in Celsius or Fahrenheit